# Pointers to pointers : error in referencing members

Tags: c, pointers, memory-leaks

Below is a simple code where I am trying to use pointers to pointers to add a node to a linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node 
{
        int data;
        struct node *next;
};

void insert(struct node **root)
{
    struct node * temp = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    if(*root == NULL)
    {
       *(root) = (struct node *) malloc (sizeof(struct node ));
       *(root)->data = 5;
       *(root)->next = temp;
    }
    else
        printf("here");
}

int main()
{
  struct node *root = NULL;
  insert(&root);
  return 0;
}
```

My understanding is that in main() a block is getting allocated to `root`. And in `insert` the address of that memory block is passed in the argument. Then it checks if their is any memory block allocated to a structure at that address and if it is NULL memory is allocated to a structure block. And this should be referenced by `*root`.But when I execute the above code I get the following error:

```
error: request for member 'data' in something not a structure or union
```

I am not able to understand where i am going wrong exactly.

Comment: `*(root)->data = 5;` -->> `(*root)->data = 5;` BTW: your code leaks the `*temp` memory on some code path. And: remove the casts, they can only do harm.

Comment: it worked!.Thanks @wildplasser. Can you please give a brief explanation about how the precedence differs in the two cases.

Comment: The others have already done that. `->` and `.` have the highest precedence ("bind tighter"); `*` is *weaker*. and `#include <malloc.h>` malloc.h is a non-standard header. You want `stdlib.h`

Comment: Use the proper header for `malloc`, which is `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: I've edited your question to refer to "pointers to pointers" rather than "double pointers". A "double pointer" could be of type `double*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` binds tighter than the dereferencing operator (`*`). See [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). So,

```
*(root)->data = 5;
```

is equivalent to:

```
*(root->data) = 5;
```

What you intended to do was:

```
(*root)->data = 5;
```

Same for the next line, which should be:

```
(*root)->next = temp;
```

Also, note that `malloc.h` is not portable. You should include C standard header `stdlib.h>` instead to get the prototype for `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

The `->` operator has a higher precedence than the dereferencing operator `*`. Refer [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for the full list. 
So the lines like

```
*(root)->data = 5;
```

will be illegal, as *first* it is trying to find a field `data` in something pointed by `root`, and obviously doesn't find it, as it is a pointer type as well.

Instead you should use the explicit precedence:

```
(*root)->data = 5;
```